# How to fetch self and friends posts on django model

Tags: django

Profile.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.png', upload_to='profile_pics')
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='user')
    bio = models.TextField(blank=True)
    friends = models.ManyToManyField("Profile", blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user.username)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/users/{}".format(self.slug)




class PostListView(ListView):
    model = PostForNewsFeed
    template_name = 'feed/home.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    ordering = ['-date_posted']
    paginate_by = 10
    count_hit = True
    slug_field = 'slug'
    
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PostListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context.update({
        'popular_posts': PostForNewsFeed.objects.order_by('-hit_count_generic__hits')[:3],
        })
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            liked = [i for i in PostForNewsFeed.objects.all() if Like.objects.filter(user = self.request.user, post=i)]
            context['liked_post'] = liked           
        return context


class PostForNewsFeed(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, max_length=100, blank=True)
    pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='path/to/img', default=None,blank=True)
    youtubeVideo = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    user_name = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tags = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    hit_count_generic = GenericRelation(HitCount, object_id_field='object_pk',
     related_query_name='hit_count_generic_relation2', default=1)
```

How to fetch Posts from self and friends posts via orm query?

```
path('', PostListView.as_view(), name='home2'),
```

Comment: How is the `PopstForNewsFeed` is linked to the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter the queryset with:

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.db.models import Q

class PostListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = PostForNewsFeed
    template_name = 'feed/home.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    ordering = ['-date_posted']
    paginate_by = 10
    count_hit = True
    slug_field = 'slug'

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs).filter(
            Q(user_name=self.request.user) |
            Q(user_name__profile__friends__user=self.request.user)
        ).distinct()

    # …
```

We thus retrieve `PostForNewsFeeds` such that the `user` of the `user_name` is the logged in user (`self.request.user`), or if the `user_name` has the logged in user in the `friends` relation.

---

> **Note**: You can limit views to a class-based view to authenticated users with the
> [**`LoginRequiredMixin`** mixin [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequired-mixin).

Comment: why am I getting an error:     path('', PostListView.as_view(), name='home2'),
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'as_view'

Comment: @sly_Chandan: did you use a decorator like `@login_required`?

Comment: @sly_Chandan: you can not use such decorator on the class. For a CBV one normally uses the `LoginRequiredMixin` as specified in the answer.

Comment: FieldError at /
Related Field got invalid lookup: user   Q(user_name__friends__user=self.request.user)

Comment: @sly_Chandan: that was a small mistake. It is a bit strange that you use a `ForeignKey` to the `User` for your `PostForNewsFeed`, instead of the `Profile`. Updated the `Q` objects.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233708/discussion-between-sly-chandan-and-willem-van-onsem).